# Mimicking C calloc array behavior in C++

Tags: c++, c, constructor, dynamic-memory-allocation, stdvector

There is some code that exists in C which uses `calloc()` to create what effectively is a vector. It looks like this:

```c
uint64_t *reverseOrder = (uint64_t *)calloc((size + 1), sizeof(uint64_t));
```

I want to mimic this behavior with C++ syntax and vectors so that it works the same de-facto. Can I use the following syntax?

```
std::vector<uint64_t> reverseOrder(size + 1, 0);
```

I know that `calloc()` actually goes through the memory and sets them to 0, so I'm wondering if this is the case.

Comment: Yes, specifying the initial value in the vector constructor is analogous to the way `calloc()` initializes the memory.

Comment: I don't think you need the `0`. Vector constructor will default initialize the elements. In the case of `uint64_t`, the default should be zero. Also the first example you have is returning a pointer, but your vector solution will make a copy of the vector, so you should _move_ the returned value to prevent needless copying

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector - number 4 is the constructor you are looking for.

Comment: Indeed, the defaulted second parameter is value-initialized (_i.e._ `uint64_t()`) which for POD types means zero-filled. So the 0 is not strictly required, and dependent on your particular preference. Personally, I would omit it.

Comment: Which could raise another, possibly even more interesting question: How to create a `std::vector<uint64_t>` instance, which is NOT default initialized?

Comment: @BitTickler you would have to `reserve()` the vector's memory and then `push_back()`/`emplace_back()` the individual values you want.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is the usual thing to do. But what if you have to pass a buffer to some low level api, which fills the buffer, not knowing it is a std::vector? For that use case, I am fresh out of ideas.

Comment: @BitTickler you can use a custom allocator that skips the initialisation

Comment: @BitTickler in C++23, you can use `std::unique_ptr<uint64_t[]>` via `std::make_unique_for_overwrite<uint64_t[]>(size+1)`. Prior to that, `std::make_unique<uint64_t[]>()` value-initializes the array elements to zeros, whereas `make_unique_for_overwrite<uint64_t[]>()` default-initializes them instead, which is a no-op. Otherwise, you can just `new[]` your own `uint64_t[]` array, just make sure you manage it correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just write

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdint>

//...

std::vector<uint64_t> reverseOrder( size + 1 );
```

and all elements of the vector will be zero-initialized.

Comment: You are one of the friendliest guys around here so +1, but it perturbs me that OP hasn't bothered to read any of https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector. Here we have a fish, not the fishing procedure.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe Thanks. Take into account that not all beginners know this link.:)

Comment: And of course knows how to parse that high density information.  That should be a source of questions!